# How can I convert list of polygons in wkt form to a multipolygon?

Tags: python, polygon, shapely

I have a list of polygons where each polygon is a `wkt` form as follows:

```
list_polygons =  ['POLYGON ((-88.131229288 41.900200029,-88.12973798 41.900104202,-88.129785999 41.894907769,-88.131352409 41.895051521,-88.131229288 41.900200029))', 
                  'POLYGON ((-88.121359263 41.887694051,-88.12027565 41.887654116,-88.120264921 41.884451192,-88.11968556399999 41.884483142,-88.11962119099999 41.882669946,-88.121251974 41.882637995,-88.121359263 41.887694051))']
```

I want to convert into a multi polygon `wkt` as:

```
'MULTIPOLYGON (((-88.131229288 41.900200029, -88.12973798 41.900104202, -88.12978599900001 41.894907769, -88.131352409 41.895051521, -88.131229288 41.900200029)), ((-88.121359263 41.887694051, -88.12027565 41.887654116, -88.120264921 41.884451192, -88.11968556399999 41.884483142, -88.11962119099999 41.882669946, -88.121251974 41.882637995, -88.121359263 41.887694051)))'
```

I tried the following but gives me `AssertionError`:

```
from shapely.geometry.multipolygon import MultiPolygon
Multipolygon(list_polygons)
```

I also tried to debug like this

```
p = wkt.loads('POLYGON ((-88.131229288 41.900200029,-88.12973798 41.900104202,-88.129785999 41.894907769,-88.131352409 41.895051521,-88.131229288 41.900200
029))')
*** SyntaxError: SyntaxError('invalid syntax', ('<string>', 1, 1, "= wkt.loads('POLYGON ((-88.131229288 41.900200029,-88.12973798 41.900104202,-88.129785999 41.894907769,-88.131352409 41.895051521,-88.131229288 41.900200029))')"))
```

What is it that I am doing wrong?

Comment: I'm assuming the `wkt` you refer to is a `shapely.wkt`. To avoid answers having to assume, please provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example with your questions. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Cross-posted: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/319546/converting-list-of-polygons-to-multipolygon-using-shapely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `list_polygons` is actually a list of strings, you need to turn them into polygons and then use the MultiPolygon constructor to create what you need:

```
import shapely.wkt as wkt
from shapely.geometry import MultiPolygon

list_string = [
    'POLYGON ((-88.131229288 41.900200029,-88.12973798 41.900104202,-88.129785999 41.894907769,-88.131352409 41.895051521,-88.131229288 41.900200029))',
    'POLYGON ((-88.121359263 41.887694051,-88.12027565 41.887654116,-88.120264921 41.884451192,-88.11968556399999 41.884483142,-88.11962119099999 41.882669946,-88.121251974 41.882637995,-88.121359263 41.887694051))'
]

c = MultiPolygon(map(wkt.loads, list_string))

print(c)
```

This example uses map, but you can apply the `wkt.loads()` function any way you like, of course.

What the line actually does: applies the `wkt.loads()` function to every element of the `list_string` list, passing the resulting iterator to the MultiPolygon constructor, which expects it to represent a collection of polygons that should represent the outsides of your shapes (not holes, that would be a second collection).